# Converting html date format to use in a nodejs route

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, html

I'm trying to send a date selection to a mysql database, which currently as the date columns formatted as dd/mm/yyyy, i'm using a standard html input date which is sending through the data as the incorrect format, and trying to change this using the js below is seemingly awkward. My convertStr function is not working.

request

```
http://localhost:1234/dateAuthor?sday=2018-01-01&eday=2018-01-01
```

js

```
   function convertStr(date){
     console.log(date)
    var date_element = date.split('.');
    var reverse_date_element =date_element.reverse();
    return reverse_date_element.join('.');
  }

  app.get('/dateAuthor',function(req,res){

    sDate = req.query.sday;
    eDate = req.query.eday;
    startDate = convertStr(sDate)
    endDate = convertStr(eDate)

    console.log(startDate, endDate)
```

ajax

```
  $("#dateGet").on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:1234/dateAuthor",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#dateGet").serialize(),
      });
    });
```

html

```
  <form action="get" id="dateGet">
  Start Date: <input type="date" name="sday">
  End Date: <input type="date" name="eday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're splitting on `'.'` but your dates are dash-separated.

Comment: i'm an idiot. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, you may try working with moment.js to manipulate dates in your project.

```js
const date = moment(sDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd', true).format('dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Otherwise, try changing your `convertStr` with `date.split('-')` and `reverse_date_element.join('/')`